# What permission is required to access node reference data?

Tags: entities, 6

I created a CCK field (`claim_category`) in a CCK type (`claim`), added a few `claim_category` nodes.

When I try to create a new `claim` node (`/node/add/claim`), admin can see the `claim_category` drop-down list fine. However, an authenticated user sees an empty drop-down list with no option in it.

What permission is required for an authenticated user to to access the drop-down list data (`claim_category` nodes)?

*Note:* CCK Content Permission module is not enabled.

Comment: Are any other access control modules active? It seems like authenticated user are not able to view claim_category nodes. Did you check that?

Comment: I found a fix. After I add a dummy CCK field in `claim_category`, the list show up properly.

Comment: If you found a solution you can add it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

After I add a dummy CCK field in `claim_category`, the list show up properly.

Answer (score 0):

ohho,

I think you have not set view and edit - 'claim_category' permission for authenticated user.

goto admin/user/permissions

set view and edit - 'claim_category' permission for authenticated user.